# 'position: absolute' responds to entire page rather than parent element

Tags: html, css

I'm new on my coding journey so apologies if this question is a bit basic, but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

I'm currently tackling this challenge on Front End Mentor: https://www.frontendmentor.io/challenges/huddle-landing-page-945317

When I use position: absolute to position elements, instead of it being positioned relative to its parent element, they seem to be positioning themselves relative to the root/body element.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  width: 1440px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.section-2 {
  height: 370px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 68%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 18px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
}

.section-2-text {
  padding: 100px 0 0 80px;
  width: 440px;
}

.grow-img {
  width: 26%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 67%;
  top: 47.5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700|Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Huddle landing page with alternating feature blocks</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="section-1">
    <div class="nav">
      <img class="logo" src="images/logo.svg" alt="">
      <a class="butn" href="mailto:name@email.com">Try it free</a>
    </div>
    <img class="mockups-img" src="images/illustration-mockups.svg" alt="">
    <h1>Build The Community<br>Your Fans Will Love</h1>
    <p>Huddle re-imagines the way we build communities. You have a voice, but so does your audience. Create connections with your users as you engage in genuine discussion.</p>
    <p>Get Started For Free</p>
  </div>

  <div class="section-2">
    <img class="grow-img" src="images/illustration-grow-together.svg" alt="">
    <div class="section-2-text">
      <h2>Grow Together</h2>
      <p class="blurb-text"> Generate meaningful discussions with your audience and build a strong, loyal community. Think of the insightful conversations you miss out on with a feedback form. </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The example I've included in the CSS concerns the iamge inthe 'grow-img' class.

Shouldn't it be positioned in relation to ? Instead, when I use top and left attributes to position the image, the start position is from the absolute top and absolute left of the page.

Comment: Elements with `position: absolute` are positioned relative **to the nearest ancestor with `position: relative`**. If you'd like `grow-img` to be positioned relatively to `section-2`, you'd add `position: relative` to  `.section-2`.

Comment: Amazing! That's solved it. Thanks so much for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when using absolute positioning, the element with absolute, needs a parent somewhere to be positioned relative. without that, it defaults to the body tag.

Comment: Cheers, that's done the trick! Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad it worked! Would you mind accepting my answer?